# Conduct audio calls with Skype bot

Tags: c#, botframework, skype

I would like to implement calls in my Skype C# bot but the examples offered don't exist or the ones that exist seem to be outdated.

I would like to know if there are any examples currently that I can deploy in Azure and how to do it in order to test it in Skype and develop it.
Thanks.

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-audio-calls?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has a detailed tutorial on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/skype-dev-bots), and you can easily deploy it with Azure.

The tutorial touches on:

- Fundamentals
- Storage
- Realtime Media
- Cognitive Services.

For what you are looking for, you should be able to find under *Realtime Media*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this has not worked for me, those examples are from 2 years ago and they seem outdated.